# Move file after creation, PyPDF2, Pandas, merge.write

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

In the below script, how can I move the files created in merger.write, to a user indicated location?

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger as PdfFileMerger


def merge_pdf(models_needed):
    for header in models_needed:
        merger = PdfFileMerger()
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            if type(row[header]) == str:
                merger.append(row[header])
        merger.write("test.pdf")
        merger.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) function from `shutil` (it is part of standard library). It basic usage is

```
import shutil
...
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

which will move `src` to `dst`. Keep in mind that as you want to use user input for second you should check if it is acceptable before using move.

Comment: How would I check for acceptability with this?

Comment: Basic check would be to see if file does not already exists, which could be done employing [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)